# Disruptor pattern with variable-duration "business logic"

Tags: multithreading, performance, latency, low-latency, disruptor-pattern

How can the disruptor be used effectively on processes where there are variable-duration "business logic" tasks? Has it been done before?

Can it be done with a second ring buffer processing the response stage? If so, how do I go about that.

I understand the Disruptor and see some specific parts of my call chain where I could apply the concept.  To be specific, the application is a middleware-type application which performs following steps:

- read inbound message, unmarshall to request
- identify customer details for request, determine workflow steps to process
- call backend system to execute steps
- collate responses, log response, marshall, and return to consumer

The issue is that some instances of the backend steps can take a "long" time, which potentially forces the response stage for short running tasks to wait for longer running tasks.  Assume call of backend system can be done either async or sync - so the idea would be that the backend system call is simply a consumer that triggers an async request to backend.

Back end system response time can be anywhere from 5ms (some requests), 50ms (90% of requests) to - 5000ms (1% of requests) (think large disk I/O).

I can see the Disruptor as potentially highly efficient but can't get my head around this hurdle to keep average latency down.

Comment: Looks like this is one answer - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/lmax-disruptor/UD6EyKDeeIw - any other suggestions ?